# Abrir app desde link

Tags: android, xml, react-native, android-manifest, aplicación-movil

He estado leyendo algunos articulos en internet, algunos que son claros pero no me sirve.

Tengo mi aplicacion desarrollada con **React Native** pero quiero aplicar la configuracion de abrir la app bajo una direccion `url` o `link`.

Estoy intentando abrir mi Aplicacion desde un `url` del navegador, ya he configurado el **AndroidManifest.xml**.

```html
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="register" android:pathPrefix="/" />
</intent-filter>
```

Ya he guardado la configuracion en la pagina web que quiero que se habra la app, y con el navegador de mi PC abre esta ventana.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir que si intenta abrir la app el navegador pero con el emulador o movil no funciona, no se si estoy omitiendo algo en la configuracion del **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Answer (score 0):

Para que funcione desde la app React Native debes declara el permiso para uso de internet (`android.permission.INTERNET`) dentro de tu Android Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
...
```

Comment: El permiso de `android.permission.INTERNET` react native lo implementa de forma automatica, es decir que ya lo tiene.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar un eventListener ha tu pantalla principal y hacer escucha de cuando en el navegador vas a visitar una pagina especifica, en esta [Pagina](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e) hay un ejemplo de como lo implemente hace un tiempo, espero te sirva de guia.

Answer (score 0):

Eso se hace agregando un intent-filter a la activity que quieres que reciba el intent. Este debe ser de acción `VIEW`, categorías `DEFAULT` y `BROWSABLE`. Finalmente en una etiqueta data introduces el link que se debería abrir en tu app.

Un ejemplo:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity
```

Fuente: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking